# Receive Cached Data after http status code 204 recevied

Tags: cocoa, caching, nsurlconnection

I use `NSURLConnection` like this

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if ( [response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
    {
        int code = [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode];
    }
}
```

I get a response whose statusCode is 204,then i send another request,but all responses i received after it will return 204, howerver the tcpdump show that the server return 200.
But after a minute, it will return 200.

I thought it might be something wrong about cache, howerver i set cachePolicy to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData and also i do `[[NSURLCahce sharedCache] removeAllCachedResponses]` before new request.

But it doesn't work. 
still i'll get 204 after the first 204, if i send the request after a minute, 200 will be get.

Is it the cache's fault? what can I do next?

PS: after a 204 arrived, if i send another request, the response arrived immediately, seems that it haven't been sent.howerver, tcpdumps catchs the send.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the NSURLRequest Class method "requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:". There you can set the cachePolicy as a NSURLRequestCachePolicy value, for example NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData. This will ignore any caches of the request stored locally.

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest =
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL
                  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                  timeoutInterval:20.0f];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,however i have tried that way, it doesn't work

kensou